# Selenium | [Errno 2] No such file or directory nul

Tags: python, selenium, file, selenium-webdriver

so i've been troubling with Selenium for quite a while now, and i noticed this error that i couldn't find the solution for.. Any ideas?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()
```

Notes:

1. Error itself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YeH6.jpg
2. msedgedriver is **IN** path, i can launch it in cmd using 'msedgedriver'
3. similar thing with chromedriver or firefoxdriver

Comment: Did you perform a restart after modifying the PATH variable on your system? Sometimes Windows can be wonky and not pickup the latest changes in certain circumstances. Also try updating the System PATH variable instead of the User one. These are long shot suggestions but have helped me in the past.

Comment: Sal, i updated both user and system paths - still doesn't work at all. Restarting is not a thing either :(

Answer (score 0):

This error is clearly due to the fact that your code cannot find `msedgedriver`.

- Download the `msedgedriver` driver for your operating system from [official MS site](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).
- If you have a Windows operating system, move the driver to `c:\Windows\System32\`. This system folder is in the system PATH for sure.
- Reboot is not required but who knows...

**Alternative solution**

Place `msedgedriver` to the folder with your code. The library starts looking for the `msedgedriver` in the current directory and if nothing is found, it looks in the system variable PATH.

Comment: Did what you said and rebooted. Still the same exact error. Honestly, i even re-installed python once again fully, but nothing changed. Do you think it could help if i'll download older version of python?

Comment: it works in my environment: OS Windows 10, python 3.9 (PyCharm and Jupyter notebook)

Comment: Try to copy `msedgedriver.exe` to the folder with our code just in case

Comment: Still nothing :(
 I even added os.chdir('path/to/folder') after that and tested with it, but still no reaction.

Comment: I installed PyCharm and tried the same thing there - still nothing. Terminal reacts to 'msedgedriver' command, but library cannot find it.